# multiple ViewControllers (containerView? childView? instance of viewController?)

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller

I need to have a new view(w/ ViewController) added over the top of another.  The user interacts with this new view for a while, and then I want to remove it.  In an older version of Xcode I was able to add it as a subview.  I now get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

I don't want the added view as a modal.  I need to see the original background through the added view.  I've read a lot about the new custom containerViews, addChildView, & presentView.  I can't see that any of these are the clear answer.

Here's the old code that worked before -
Action in the main ViewController:

```
-(IBAction)showWhiteView:(id)sender
{
    WhiteViewController *whiteView = [[WhiteViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WhiteViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:whiteView.view];
}
```

Action in the added view to remove it:

```
-(IBAction)removeView:(id)sender
{
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Maybe a VISUAL EXAMPLE will help explain - Let's say the main view is an ocean, with animated waves and clouds moving controlled by MainView Controller.  The user taps something and a I want to add a boat(WhiteView) to the main view.  I want the user to interact with boat: tap here the sail opens, tap there the anchor drops, etc. (needing the methods of the WhiteViewController) Eventually I want to remove the boat from the ocean.

Thanks Tim - New code added:

```
-(IBAction)showWhiteView:(id)sender
{   WhiteViewController *whiteView = [[WhiteViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WhiteViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self addChildViewController:whiteView];
    [whiteView didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self.view addSubview:whiteView.view];   }
```

and within the WhiteViewController to remove:

```
-(IBAction)removeView:(id)sender
{    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
     [self removeFromParentViewController];    }
```

I look forward to any further suggestions on making this better.
Thanks all!

Comment: you can not remove the base view or parent view. you can add your child view upon a parent view. so if you remove parent view you get the EXE_BAD error

Comment: I'm adding the WhiteView as a child(sub) to the main view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8379759/how-does-view-controller-containment-work-in-ios-5/8379894#8379894) concerning UIViewController containment.  I put together an example project on UIViewController containment here: http://github.com/toolmanGitHub/stackedViewControllers

Hope this helps.``

Tim

Comment: Thanks Tim!  Looking at your example lead me to a solution.  I was only adding the view & not its controller.  So I added to the original code.  see above.

Comment: Tim,  I have a related problem.  I'm trying to have my child view controller message the parent.  I've tried an adaptation of your "[(ViewController *)self.parentViewController swapViewControllers];" from your example code.  It keeps telling me "No visible @interface for 'UIViewController' declares the selector 'myMethod'"  I've imported the parent viewcontroller.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @Scott make sure the .h file for your parent view controller contains the declaration of 'myMethod'.  And then also make sure the (ViewController *) is in fact the parent view controller name that you are importing.

Comment: That's it.  Once again you saved the day.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

what I understood from your question is, that you want to add a subview to a superview, and which must be user interactable right?

so you can do it by following steps.

> 1) Add a new view to the xib.
>     2) make it opaque, set is alpha to less than one(but not zero, depends on you, how much trasparancy u want)
>    3) add the componats over it,
>   and inside `-(IBAction)showWhiteView:(id)sender` (in your case) the following code

```
whiteView.frame = CGRectMake(55, 60, 200, 200);
[UIView beginAnimations:@"" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:.5];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.view cache:YES];
[self.view addSubview:whiteView];
```

And to remove it do the following

```
-(IBAction)removeView:(id)sender
  {
     [whiteView removeFromSuperview];
  }
```

Dont forget to connect the newly added view.

try it out.

Comment: I'm not sure that is the key.  It's really about bringing the methods in the ViewController in the added Subview.